# Getting Error: Type 'Teacher[]' is not assignable to type 'Teacher'

Tags: angular

I am trying to add a service to my angular application, but I don't know how to fix the next error:

Type 'Teacher[]' is not assignable to type 'Teacher'.
  Property 'name' is missing in type 'Teacher[]'.

```
export const TEACHERS: Teacher[] = [
  { name:'Negrut Marioara' ,gender: "Female" ,subject: 'Romanian' },
  { name:'Nagy Ridi Eniko' ,gender: "Female" ,subject: 'Maths' },
  { name: 'Sarkadi Viktoria' ,gender: "Female" ,subject: 'Hungarian' },
  { name:'Flonta Ioan' ,gender: "Male" ,subject: 'Latin' },
  { name:'Nagyvari Eniko' ,gender: "Female" ,subject: 'Physics' },
];
=============================================================================================
    export class Teacher {
    name: string;
    subject: string;
    gender: string;
  }
=====================================================================================================
@Component({
  selector: 'app-teachers',
  templateUrl: './teachers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./teachers.component.css']
})
export class TeachersComponent implements OnInit {

  teachers: Teacher
  selectedTeacher: Teacher;
  onSelect(teacher: Teacher): void {
    this.selectedTeacher = teacher;
  }
  constructor(private teacherService: TeacherService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getTeachers();
  }
  getTeachers(): void {
    this.teachers = this.teacherService.getTeachers();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message means that an array of `Teacher` cannot be assigned to a property that has been declared as a single `Teacher`. You need to update your declaration so that it is an array:

```
teachers: Teacher[];
```

The clue was in the error message all along

> Type 'Teacher[]' is not assignable to type 'Teacher'

Answer (score 1):

In your component, property `teachers` should be typed as `array`.

```
teachers : Teachers[]
```